# PhpMyAdmin - отображение русских символов в неправильной кодировке (именно отображение, данные - в верной кодировке)

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, phpmyadmin, pdo

Данные записываю и извлекаю в нужной кодировке (`utf-8`), проблема именно в отображении данных в `PhpMyAdmin`. Как видно на скриншоте - кодировка в браузере неверно отображается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сама строка:

> SCP-527 - Ð“-Ð½ Ð Ñ‹Ð±Ð°BBPE!!!!!2ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚, Ð¼Ð¸Ñ€BBPE!!!!!2SCP-2032 - ÐžÑ‚ÐµÑ† Ð’Ñ€ÐµÐ¼Ñ

Вот структура таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это поправить? Оно не критично совершенно, но я страдаю.

**UPD_0:**

На запрос `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'` выдаёт следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD_1:**

Подключался к БД из `php` скрипта через `PDO`, задавая кодировку вот так:

```
$charset="utf-8";
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
```

И как верно заметил @artoodetoo, чёрточка была лишней. Кодировку для БД надо было указать так:

```
$charset="utf8";
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37105/discussion-on-question-by--phpmyadmin-----).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Данные записываю и извлекаю в нужной кодировке

Это вам так кажется. Поддерживаю ответ Andrew Hobbit, но считаю, что необходимо объяснение причины:

Похоже, что у вас данные в таблице испорчены, т.к. вы не указывете `"SET NAMES …"` в своём приложении. Для конкретных интерфейсов доступа есть специальные функции для этого. Например в консольной утилите mysql это команда `charset`, а в PHP расширении mysqli это функция `mysqli_set_charset()`.

Дело в том, что MySQL должен знать с какой кодировкой работает клиент. Сервер умеет на лету перекодировать из вашей клиентской кодировки в кодировку таблицы и обратно. Если вы НЕ указали свою кодировку, то сервер может предполагать, что вам нужна какая-нибудь 1252.

Пока вы пишете и читаете только из одного места, вы можете не догадываться о проблеме, ведь перекодирование при записи и чтении делаются зеркально. Но стоит зайти в "правильное" место, как например phpMyAdmin, как вы видите, что данные у вас совсем НЕ в UTF-8!

**UPDATE**:

Важно! Если в http и html вы везде пишете 'UTF-8' через чёрточку, то в MySQL надо писать 'UTF8' без чёрточки.

Comment: да, ура, всё дело было в чёрточке в кодировке в `php` файле при создании `pdo` подключения к БД. Спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

"Кракозябры" в строке - следствие отображения UTF-8 в cp1252. В cp1252 нет кириллических символов. Данные в таблице могут быть в правильной кодировке, но клиент (скрипт) может просить данные в другой кодировке. Если данные в базе, например, utf8, а клиент просит в cp1251, то все будет нормально отображаться, перекодировка будет "на лету" происходить. В случае с cp1252 будет беда, из-за отсутствия кириллицы. У phpMyAdmin есть пункт в конфиге `$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation']` устанавливающий кодировку по-умолчанию при подключении, подробнее в [документации](https://pma.nic.ru/doc/html/config.html#basic-settings). Для определения кодировки мне нравится такая "помогалка" [image: шпаргалка по кодировкам]. Самый простой вариант - везде использовать utf8, в настройках сервера, БД, php и т.д. Очень понятно про кодировки и работу с БД описано в [статье](http://phpfaq.ru/mysql/charset)